# Angular js filter dict with list values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Alright i am repeating a list of events that are in a dict with ng-repeat and for the life of me i can't get the $filter to only display the ones in a list only....

```
var list-to-match = ["bike", "car", "whatever"]
```

right now i'm using

```
ng-repeat="e in eventlist | filter:searchList(e)"

scope.searchList = function(e){
console.log(e)
}
```

I keep getting undefined.

```
}
  "schedules": [
    {
      "activitytype": "Basic", 
      "eventurl": "agxzfmlzc2Nob29saW5yFgsSDlNjaG9vbFNjaGVkdWxlGOz4BAw", 
      "locationName": "Staunton",
      "start": "2012-11-21", 
      "starttime": "02:00 PM", 

    }, 
    {
      "activitytype": "bike", 
      "eventurl": "agxzfmlzc2Nob29saW5yFgsSDlNjaG9vbFNjaGVkdWxlGOz4BAw", 
      "locationName": "Hilltop",
      "start": "2012-11-21", 
      "starttime": "02:00 PM", 
    }
}
```

Here is part of it... Sorry

alright so i decided to write a filter for it from a couple i saw... don't know if its the best way and any thoughts would be appreciative.

```
.
filter('byMySport', function () {
    return function (eventlist, mysports) {
        var items = {
            mysports: mysports,
            out: []
        };
console.log(eventlist);
        angular.forEach(eventlist, function (valueEvent, key) {
            angular.forEach(mysports, function (value, key) {
                        if (value == valueEvent.activitytype) {
                        this.out.push(valueEvent);
                        }
            }, items);
        }, items);
        return items.out;
    };
})
```

Comment: What if you skip passing the argument, i.e. `filter:searchList`?  Add `console.log(arguments);` for debugging too and show the results.

Comment: When you say "events" do you mean the "bike", "car, "whatever"? And are you filtering the keys or values? Or does the list correspond to some key?

Comment: I get the event object in the console, why does that show up?

Comment: i'm using the list to filter out the events that don't have bike or car or "whatever" as a value in the events dict.

Comment: Can you give me a small part of the dictionary that you're working with?

Comment: Sorry i edited above, It was just a part i grabbed...

Comment: and technically its not a dict its a object... don't know why i called it that...lol

Comment: Are you saying that it works now?

Comment: Ya, sorry about taking so long to get back.  It works with the above filter.  I would like to think you because if someone wasn't trying to help me i would have given up. lol